# How to I hide specific file in File App of Device

Tags: ios

First of all I know this is a subjective question, not code based, How ever I need to find solution. Please provide any references

I am working on a task in which I saving the files in Device Document directory. Upto here all is working fine. However when I see these files from :

> Files App -> App Folder and the files

I can see all those files.

Now I want to hide few of them, How can I achieve these....?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per your requirement. You need to change some lines of code in saving file.

Firstly, The `FileApp` shows all the data that save in documentsDirectory of app whether you put code for hide or not. To hide few files you need to make separate path for them.

First, the file you want to show in documentDirectory:

```
let documentsDirectory = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
```

The file you don’t want to show with user, you need to create path here:

```
let libraryDirectory = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
```

Once you set the library path for saving all your important files. All will be hidden and cannot be accessed by user.

To know more about files, please refer to this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4 or Xcode 8 • Swift 3**

```
extension URL {
    var isHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.isHiddenKey]))?.isHidden == true
        }
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.isHidden = newValue
            do {
                try setResourceValues(resourceValues)
            } catch {
                print("isHidden error:", error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for more reference see chain here [Cocoa Swift, get/set hidden flag on files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741823/cocoa-swift-get-set-hidden-flag-on-files-and-directories)

or

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html

Comment: @Kanhaiya Thank you for posting an answer. I have tried this, however the hiding of files work in documents directory, not in FIle App -> App Folder -> File. And I have read these links, I don't get the point for what I want....Can you understand this.....and can you more clarify for this....?